# Keep footer at the bottom of the page but make the page grow as needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this CSS code for a footer:

```
.footer {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:40px;
    position:absolute !important;
    bottom:0; !important;
}
```

What I need to do is to be able to make the page to grow as the elements above the footer grows like textbox or something above it. However the code above makes the footer stick and the elements above overlaps with the footer.

Is there a quick CSS fix for this kind of scenario or jQuery is needed for this?

Comment: page to grow? what do you mean by that ?, can you give me some illustration of the current issue ? any example ? etc ?

Comment: @NeophytePolyhistor like this http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a sticky footer: take a look at [my article](http://slick.pl/kb/webdesign/webdesign-sticky-footer-czyli-przylegajaca-stopka-strony/).

It's written in polish but you have both CSS and XHTML extra easy to understand. Feel free to use it. :)

Comment: The example is older than you think but does the job. If you have nothing valuable to add then do a break.

Comment: @slick what's the catch that made the footer pushed below, was is height: auto; of the element above the footer?

Answer (score 0):

`Check` this out ;

[Sticky Footer](http://codepen.io/mfritsch/pen/dPqjdy)

Or in specific, you can use these properties for your **CSS** on footer:

```
footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
  height: 300px;
  background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #31353A;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
}
```

**Only** while you have your main contents set to `position: relative;`
I hope it helped.

Answer (score -1):

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jyd477hL/)

```
.site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: The fiddle works, but this code would not work with UIKit (getuikit.com)

Comment: So much fanny ache over one downvote? Calm thy chest, fair knite.